# Python -- What is the best practice to append query params to url for API calls

Tags: python, urlparse

I know this sounds weird at first glance. Let me explain.

I have a domain that stays consistent, say `https://some.api.endpoint/some/path`

I have a list of different queries I need to call with it. One way to do it is simple concatenating strings but then I have to deal with encoding, something I try to avoid.

So I decided to go with using urlparse -> urlunparse. I'm not sure if this is a good practice, but this can work.

```
url = 'https://some.api.endpoint/some/path'
parsed = urlparse(url)
parsed=parsed._replace(query='search=some_name')
new_url = urlunparse(parsed)
response = requests.get(new_url)
```

My questions:

1. is it even a good practice?
2. If it's okay to do so without the `urlunparse` part?
3. What would be a better way to do it?

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `requests` documentation, you can pass a dictionary to the `params` keyword argument of `requests.get`. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

```
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', params=payload)
```

That'll handle the url encoding and everything for you.

Result from the above snippet:

```
print(r.url)
# http://httpbin.org/get?key2=value2&key1=value1
```

Comment: seems like I was focusing on the wrong part of things hahaha. Thanks